# How to split range of number and calculate total range?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, substring

I want to fetch page range from my DB column `pages` from table `articles`

```
|article_id|pages|

    1       41-47
    2       60-61
```

which the output is for article id 1:

```
<fpage>41</fpage>
<lpage>47</lpage>
```

and here is my code:

```
$page = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pages FROM articles WHERE article_id='1'")  or die(mysql_error());

while($page2=mysqli_fetch_array($page))
 {
    result = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($m)
   {
        return implode(',', range($m[1], $m[2]));
    }, $page2);

    $page3 = explode(',', $result['pages']);
    $xml .= '<fpage>'.$page3[0].'</fpage>';
    $xml .= '<lpage>'.$page3[6].'</lpage>';

}
```

I manage to get for lastpage of article 1 using `array [6]`. So how to do for the article that might have different range? And also, I want to **calculate the page range** ,

for article 1 the total page range (41-47) is 6, but I don't know how to do it. Your Help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**SUBSTRING_INDEX()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to split the string:

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(pages, '-', 1) AS fpage, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(pages, '-', -1) AS lpage, 
      (SUBSTRING_INDEX(pages, '-', -1) - SUBSTRING_INDEX(pages, '-', 1)) AS pageRange
FROM articles 
WHERE article_id = '1';
```